# Drop-Down isn't populated with the 'name' field when table name contains "companies"

Tags: cakephp

**I have this very strange issue I cannot explain:**

The table `drivers` has the `belongsTo` association to the table `transport_companies` connected by the field `drivers.transport_company_id`. Usually in the `edit`|`add` mode for the table `drivers` CakePHP generates a nice drop-down with the content of the `name` field.

**The issue:**

The drop-drown shows only the ids instead of the content of the `name` field as long the table has the word `companies` in it. When I rename the table to `transport_firms` | `transports` | `transport_units` or something else then the drop-down field is populated correctly. I do NOT change anything, I only bake all models each time I rename the table.

**My question:**

Is there any CakePHP restriction regarding the word `companies` in a tablename because the drop-down isn't populated correctly?

Comment: Singularizing `companies` is different than all your other examples. Cake is supposed to handle such situations correctly, and I've never had any problems with it (I have a "securities" table, for example, which worked fine). It is possible to add your own singular/plural logic, did you maybe do that to support some other non-standard conversion? If so, perhaps what you added somehow broke this one?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I don't understand 100% what you mean. I am not using any non-standard conversion and I didn't add anything. Where should it be? As you already _know_ I have this _general_ script handling all requests. I am **NOT** touching/modifying the entity and table PHP scripts. When I changed the database structure I run `bin/cake models all` and press `a` so the old files are overwritten. That's all. Because I use the `Crud` plugin all of the Controller files are totally empty. And, the table `vehicle_categories` works correctly in the drop-down. Therefore I am very confused.

Comment: Here's [the documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/inflector.html#loading-custom-inflections) on what I was talking about. Thought it was a long shot, but can't think of any other reason for this sort of issue.

Comment: @GregSchmidt OK, I am aware of this function but what should I do? What is CakePHP expecting for the table `transport_companies`? As I am not _violating_ with some personalised conversions the standard behaviour this is how CakePHP resolves `companies` at the end of a table name which apparently is buggy.

Comment: I don't have any good suggestion for you, apart from carefully debugging what's going on during the generation of the edit page to see if maybe there's some bad configuration somewhere. And if you find such an issue, then debugging the bake process to see why it's being generated incorrectly. How to go about doing that is far beyond anything I could ever write down.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Suddenly some on-the-fly-generated `edit` views have this behaviour and some not for the same table. I have to investigate further so I can provide you even more accurate information. I am not saying I don't have somewhere a bad configuration. Thx

Comment: If some are now working that weren't before, is there any chance that it's just your ORM cache that's messing it up?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Add your last comment as an answer. This was exactly the problem. I ran `cake cache clear_all` and now all works even for the table `transport_companies`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Greg Schmidt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4987673/greg-schmidt) comment was the important hint. The CakePHP caches got messed up and - according to my another comment - another references began to fail as well.

I avoid this issue running these commands **each time I make a change in the database**:

```
bin/cake cache clear_all && bin/cake bake model all
```

As I don't add any code to the model/table and entity files I can always overwrite all of them. This simplifies the maintenance substantially.